Lenovo Laptop Not Waking from Lid Close Suspend on Ubuntu 24.04
I have a Lenovo Thinkpad P1Gen6 Laptop with NVidia graphics card that has been working fine with Ubuntu 22.04.  I recently wiped and installed Ubuntu 24.04 and found the suspend would not properly wake up when invoked with a lid close.  When opening the lid the laptop screen would briefly show some text and the display goes dark.  The keyboard lights work and remain responsive, but only a dark screen leading to a hard reboot to recover.
The suspend works just fine when invoked from the power button on the top menu.
My problem was very similar to not waking up from suspend ubuntu 22.04 so I tried without any success.
How can I get the lid close suspend to function as expected and as the menu invoked suspend does.

After troubleshooting with many re-installs toggling multiple options including BIOS security chip, secure boot, LVM encrypted, LVM non-encrypted, default disk format, I found a working solution, however, I am not able to reproduce nor do I know exactly what I did to get rid of the problem.
Since I had done several re-installs removing the security chip, secure boot, encryption options the problem was very reproducible.  My best guess is the BIOS factory reset cleared something that was causing the problem.  Given the up-vote of the BIOS Security Chip setting, my suspicion leans towards that, but I have no proof.
Happily my computer does wake up properly from a lid invoked suspend now.
